# How can we change the default settings for Save Query result to File in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

SSMS seems to be missing the option for configuring "exporting query results to file"

Please is there a way we can configure this?

The default export query results to file:

- lacks TAB separated column
- adds a summary row
- adds header columns
- adds an annoying header underline

If we could alter these defaults, *the query results to file output* would be easily reusable with a simple  `bulk insert [table] from 'file path'` statement

[image]

Comment: `Results to Text` is actually the `Results to file` , also if you check it is set to Tab delimited on your screen shot, check the first checkbox to add column names. Make sure you select `Results To File` before executing the query from SSMS and it should save the output to a file with all the mentioned properties.

Comment: @ ran those settings but no luck

Comment: If you need more control exporting query results to a file, there's always SSIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSMS will export the same things defined (and displayed) as if you would run a `Result to Text`. In fact, you can define everything under the menu point `Result to Text` and it will work for both.

If your missing something here, you can also use `BCP` (more infos [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802(v=sql.120).aspx)) or `PowerShell` to export data from an table, view or procedure.